# Why my password EditText don't save my input?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, gettext

So, after I input my text in password EditText it is not saved. But rest of EditText inputs works well. What am I do wrong with password EditText?
I tried everything what I could but I constantly get empty password.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
public Spinner countriesList ;
public Button btnRegistration, pickImgBtn;
private ConstraintLayout mainConstrain;
private EditText name , email, password, reEnterPassword;
private CheckBox iAgree;
public RadioGroup radioGroup;


private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
private ImageView imageView;
private Uri imageUri;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    countriesList=findViewById(R.id.countrySpinnerId);

    mainConstrain=findViewById(R.id.mainConstrainId);

    btnRegistration=findViewById(R.id.btnRegisterId);
    pickImgBtn=findViewById(R.id.pickImgBtnId);

    //Input
    name=findViewById(R.id.nameId);
    email=findViewById(R.id.emailId);
    password=findViewById(R.id.passwordId);
    reEnterPassword=findViewById(R.id.reEnterPasswordId);

    radioGroup=findViewById(R.id.radioGroupId);

    //CheckBox
    iAgree=findViewById(R.id.iAgreeId);

    imageView=findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    setCountriesList(countriesList);





    btnRegistration.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showSnackbar("You have registered: ");
            checkInputData(radioGroup,iAgree,password,reEnterPassword,name,email);
            addNewPeople(name,email,password,countriesList,radioGroup);
            setStartData(name,email,password,reEnterPassword,iAgree);
        }
    });
```

This is second part of code!

```
public void addNewPeople(EditText name, EditText email, EditText password,Spinner contries, RadioGroup group) {
    if (!(name.getText().toString().equals("")) && !(email.getText().toString().equals("")) && !(password.getText().toString().equals("")))
       SecondaryActivity.peoples.add(new People(name.getText().toString(), email.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString(),contries.getSelectedItem().toString() , group.getCheckedRadioButtonId()));
    else
        showSnackbar("Fill all fields");

}
```

This is code for setting data to be empty after click on button.

```
  private void setStartData(EditText name,EditText email,EditText password, EditText reEnterPassword, CheckBox iAgree) {
    name.setText("");
    email.setText("");
    password.setText("");
    reEnterPassword.setText("");
    iAgree.setChecked(false);
}

private void checkInputData(RadioGroup radioGroup,CheckBox iAgree, EditText password, EditText reEnterPassword,EditText name,EditText email) {
   if (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1  )
     radioGroup.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

   if (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1 )
       radioGroup.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

   if (!(iAgree.isChecked()))
       iAgree.setTextColor(Color.RED);

    if (iAgree.isChecked())
        iAgree.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

    // is Password same
    if (password.getText().toString().equals(reEnterPassword.getText().toString())) {
        password.setText("");
        reEnterPassword.setText("");
        password.setHint("Password are not same");
        password.setHintTextColor(Color.RED);
    }

    //Input name, email and pass emptiness check

        if (name.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            name.setHint("Unesi ime");
            name.setHintTextColor(Color.RED);
        }else{
            name.setHintTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        }

        if (email.getText().toString().equals("")){
            email.setHint("Unesi email");
            email.setHintTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
        else{
            email.setHintTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        }


        if (password.getText().toString().equals("")){
            password.setHint("Unesi password.....");
            password.setHintTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
        else{
            password.setHintTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        }
}
```

I hope someone can help

Answer (score 0):

From what you're saying, I assume that this piece of code is always being executed:

```
if (password.getText().toString().equals("")){
            password.setHint("Unesi password.....");
            password.setHintTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
```

Am I right?

Are you sure that the id used in findViewById is the right one?
If I were you, I would put a break point inside the setOnClickListener call to checkInputData.

Comment: Yes, my this piece of code i always executed.I checked findViewById and it is good.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your logic.

```
// is Password same
if (password.getText().toString().equals(reEnterPassword.getText().toString())) {
    password.setText("");
    reEnterPassword.setText("");
    password.setHint("Password are not same");
    password.setHintTextColor(Color.RED);
}
```

It should be like this

```
// if the Password is not same
if (!password.getText().toString().equals(reEnterPassword.getText().toString())) {
    password.setText("");
    reEnterPassword.setText("");
    password.setHint("Password are not same");
    password.setHintTextColor(Color.RED);
}
```

password and re-enter password must be same

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the password is empty or not like this:

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(edittext.gettext())){
    //Your logic here
}
else {
    //Do something else.
}
```

- TextUtils.isEmpty() method can be used to check if the string is empty or not. You can also use str.equals(""), but with edittext, it can cause a crash if you get an empty string from edittext. So TextUtils.isEmpty() is the safest method here.
- Also, Put some Toast or Log in the related blocks to check the values you are getting from password edittext. It can give you clear idea of the values you are getting.

And yes! Your password checking logic is also wrong. So check that as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Issue in this logic**

```
// is Password same
    if (password.getText().toString().equals(reEnterPassword.getText().toString())) {
        password.setText("");
        reEnterPassword.setText("");
        password.setHint("Password are not same");
        password.setHintTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
```

**Just you are missing ! operator**

```
// is Password same
    if (!password.getText().toString().equals(reEnterPassword.getText().toString())) {
        password.setText("");
        reEnterPassword.setText("");
        password.setHint("Password are not same");
        password.setHintTextColor(Color.RED);
    }
```